# Entering value into Excel sheet at particular location only thru linq to excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-excel

My Excel sheet is as below:

```
Id   Name  Status
1    XYZ
2    ABC
3    BB
1    Yz
```

What I am trying to do is to write `Checked` in the status column whose Id is 1 from my C# application.

I thought of doing this through Linq to Excel. But I am not getting anything positive in this direction.

Can anyone guide me properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are out of luck here, as Linq-To-Excel does not write to spreadsheets ([reference](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/issues/14)).
The only option you have is to strongly type your queries, modifiy the results in memory and save them as a .csv to your harddisk - or use another 3rd party library to write the changes back to the excel file.

```
public class Demo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

string pathToExcelFile = @"path\to\file.xslx";  
string sheetName = "Tabelle1";

var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
    //strongly type the result
Demo rowToUpdate = (from xc in excelFile.Worksheet<Demo>(sheetName) 
                   where xc.ID == 1
                   select xc).FirstOrDefault();
    //update retrieved record
rowToUpdate.Status = "Active";
    //output in linqpad
rowToUpdate.Dump();
    //no submitchanges or save method available :(
```

Comment: Thanks serv for your reply.I will look into other possibilites

Comment: Why no submitchanges or save method available ?? Any alternatives for these please?